# Having the beamer class - How can I insert the Table of Contents over 2 frames and also insert it in front of every section?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm working on a presentation and in front of every section I want that a frame is inserted where I can see the table of contents with the section I'm about to start written in a normal way and the remaining things in a faded way, like here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqJVX.jpg

Also I want to know how I can split the ToC on 2 frames since mine is too long for putting it on just one frame; 
I read a lot about it and either [allowframebreaks] or [allowframebreaks=frac] is suggested but with the fraction it looks really messy and without it separates the ToC in a very brutal way - I wish that everything that belongs to one section is not being separated;
Do you have any idea?

The code of a minimum example can be found here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}

%--------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%--------------------------------------

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usecolortheme{lily}

}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Table of Contents} %
\tableofcontents 
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES

  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
bla bla
\end{frame}

\section{test2}
\begin{frame}
bla bla
\end{frame}

\section{test3}
\begin{frame}
bla bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{subtest1}
\begin{frame}
    bla bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{subtest2}
\begin{frame}
    bla bla
\end{frame}

\section{tes4}
\begin{frame}
bla bla
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to easily split the ToC automatically, but once you have your overall document structure finished, you can easily restrict the table of contents on a particular slide to a subset of sections using something like `\tableofcontents[sections={1-2}]`.

Fading out other sections with transparency is done with the `hideothersubsections` option for the `\tableofcontents` command.

Adding a slide automatically at a section start is most easily done with the `\AtBeginSection` command.

The ToC commands are documented in Section 10.5 of the [beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), and the `\AtBeginSection` command is in section 10.2.

Complete example, with added content commands to make testing easier:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newcommand{\simplesection}[1]{
\section{#1}
\begin{frame}
  bla bla
\end{frame}
}
\newcommand{\complexsection}[1]{
\section{#1}
\subsection{subtest1}
\begin{frame}
  bla bla
\end{frame}
\subsection{subtest2}
\begin{frame}
  bla bla
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents[sections={1-2}]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents[sections={3-4}]
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection{
  \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}

\simplesection{test}
\simplesection{test2}
\complexsection{test3}
\simplesection{test4}

\end{document}
```

[image]